# What is this component and how can I drive it?

Tags: identification, high-voltage

A long time ago as a kid I disassembled a plasma globe. Inside was a small board with a box-like plastic-enclosed component. This component has a long wire which leads up to the center of the plasma globe. For a long time, I used this circuit for some experiments with HV. However, the circuit has been practically destroyed while I was shipping it (mechanical damage). This main component seems fine though, so I have removed it from the board.

I would like to be able to salvage this part. Can anyone provide a data sheet or any information about how I can power this, and what exactly it is? It has two pins on one side of the bottom face, and five pins on the other side of the bottom face. The only marking is a label which reads "HL-66". I've attached a couple images for reference:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If it comes from a plasma globe, it can be a transformer  but hard to says without more clues

Comment: @francoisP What other information can I provide to help with ID?

Comment: You can try measuring resistance between each pin (including the long wire) to get an idea what pins are even connected inside.

Comment: I have seen this kind before. Some taps are driven by 12 VDC and a PWM controlled MOSFET or fast NPN. Another pin outputs a voltage that increases with load, i.e. touching the globe to make it stream to your finger, used as a current throttle. The current throttle keeps the current from getting high enough to shock you and keep the MOSFET from burning up. A typical PWM IC is the TL494.